# How to search youtube video in channel using youtube

Tags: python, search, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
def get_videos(search_keyword):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME,
                  YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                  developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
  try:
    search_response = youtube.search().list(
      q=search_keyword, 
      part="id,snippet",
      channelId=os.environ.get("CHANNELID", None),
      maxResults=10, #max = 50, default = 5, min = 0
      ).execute()
    videos = []
    channels = []
    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
      if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
         title = search_result["snippet"]["title"]
         videoId = search_result["id"]["videoId"]
         channelTitle = search_result["snippet"]["channelTitle"]
         cam_thumbnails = search_result["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["medium"]["url"]
         publishedAt = search_result["snippet"]["publishedAt"]
         channelId = search_result["snippet"]["channelId"]
         data = {'title' : title,
                 'videoId' : videoId,
                 'channelTitle' : channelTitle,
                 'cam_thumbnails' : cam_thumbnails,
                 'publishedAt' : publishedAt}
        videos.append(data)
       elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#channel":
          channels.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                      search_result["id"]["channelId"]))


   except Exception as e:
     print e
```

Now, I'am using python youtube data api, I get youtube video data that is searched by keyword in specified channel, But I want to get All data that is not searched by keyword in specified channel

How get I youtube video data in specified channel? data that i want to get must be all data in specified channel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I know what you're asking, but I *think* you're asking how you can get all videos in a channel and not just those related to your keyword? If that's correct, you should just be able to remove:

```
 q=search_keyword,
```

from your request, and the API should then return all videos in the channel. If you're asking something else, please clarify in your question.

Comment: thank you for reply, that problem is solved for your reply, good luck!